# Getting Error LIke:malloc: *** error for object 0xa2b6f50: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: ios6, malloc, breakpoints

I am Using xcode 4.6 with ARC enabled.I want to add some images to the UItableview row from server. 
i am getting the error like :

malloc: *** error for object 0xa2b6f50: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Here is my Code :

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[templateURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[[templateArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"options_picture"]]];

```
        UIImageView *templateView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x1, y1, wid, ht)];
        NSLog(@"templeteArray %@",imageURL);

         AsyncronousUIImage *image=[[AsyncronousUIImage alloc]init];
        [image loadImageFromURL:imageURL inImageView:templateView];
        image.delegate=self;
        [templateScroll addSubview:templateView];
```

The AsyncronousUIImage class is as below:

```
 - (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL *)anUrl inImageView:(UIImageView*)imgView{

imageView = imgView;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:anUrl
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                                  timeoutInterval:30.0];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {

if (data == nil)
 data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];

[data appendData:incrementalData];

     }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection
     {
          [self initWithData:data];
           data = nil;
          connection = nil;
         [self.delegate imageDidLoad:self];
      }
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply make the file ARC disabled in which your adding this code. try that at first...
and for that purpose use the answer from this question [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)